# How do I make Gradle 8+ compile Groovy code before Kotlin code? and mix them in one project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, migration

Using a very recent version of gradle (8.5) I want to compile Groovy code ***before*** Kotlin code. This will enable me to *gradually* migrate the entire project from Groovy to Kotlin using a top-down approach. (i.e., migrate one controller to Kotlin while the underlying dependencies remain in Groovy).

The Kotlin gradle plugin seems to update the task requirements, forcing the Kotlin compilation to happen first.

- Kotlin plugin wants to happen after the `compileJava`
- Groovy plugin wants to perform `compileJava` first
  Thus, I can't do a compileGroovy without it triggering a compileKotlin which prevents my goal from above.

TaskTree ouptut:

```
:compileGroovy
\--- :compileJava
     \--- :compileKotlin
          \--- :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
```

plugins used in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '2.0.0-Beta2'
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "2.1.1"
    id 'idea'
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. place a Groovy class file in `src/main/groovy` (i.e., Author)
2. place a Kotlin class file in `src/main/kotlin` that depends on that Groovy class. (i.e., Book)

Additional research notes:

- The solution provided for an earlier Gradle version is no longer working:
  [Gradle 6+ : compile groovy before kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138147/gradle-6-compile-groovy-before-kotlin) (there is an error message about 'classpath' as unknown property for compileKotlin)
- Here is another one that does not work:
  [Compile Groovy and Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214437/compile-groovy-and-kotlin)
- And yet another approach that no longer works: [Gradle Kotlin Dsl Build for a Kotlin Gradle Plugin, which depends on a Groovy Class in the same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210081/gradle-kotlin-dsl-build-for-a-kotlin-gradle-plugin-which-depends-on-a-groovy-cl)

Comment: If your Groovy code doesn't need to depend on the Kotlin code, I would simply place your Kotlin code in a new module that depends on the old Groovy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base idea of the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sub:compile_deps_jvm_lang and thus the solution in [Gradle 6+ : compile groovy before kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138147/gradle-6-compile-groovy-before-kotlin) you posted stays the same.

You remove the `groovy => java` dependency and add a `kotlin => groovy` dependency.

That the linked answer does not literally work has nothing to do with Gradle 6 vs. Gradle 8.

Your problem is Kotlin Gradle Plugin <1.8 vs. >=1.8 as in 1.8 the deprecated `classpath` property was finally made an error and later removed, in favor of `libraries`.

So here the version of the configuration that works with your version as Kotlin DSL snippet:

```kotlin
tasks.compileGroovy {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.get().compileClasspath
}

tasks.compileKotlin {
    libraries.from(sourceSets.main.get().groovy.classesDirectory)
}
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!   I was trying to modify the `groovy => java` dependency manually and encountering "removing a task dependency from a task is not supported". Why does changing the `compileGroovy` classpath remove that dependency?

Comment: Because task dependencies are usually not configured explicitly. Outputs are wired to inputs and carry implicit task dependencies. So by having the output of the Java compile task wired to the `classpath` input of the Groovy compile task, the dependency of the Groovy compile task to the Java compile task is implied properly.